# How do I hide panel handles ("hide buttons") in Gnome?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gnome-panel

I am running 11.04 and sometimes I need to take a screenshot of a full-screen application - and the Gnome panels on top and bottom are usually in the way.

So, I can click the "hide buttons" (panel handles?) on left and right of each panel bar, and then the panel goes left or right - however, the handle itself is still visible, and "always on top" - so again it ends in the screenshot.

Is there any way to hide the panel handles completely?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's possible - albeit a bit tricky: right click on the panel handle, choose "Properties" - "Panel Properties" starts up; here check the "Autohide" option, click "Close".

The important part here, is that "hide" **doesn't** work, if the panels are "collapsed" (that is, only the handles are visible on top in screen corner) - so first "expand" the top and bottom panel; then wait for a second or two - and then the panels will go upward (or downward, respectively) outside of the screen, and so will finally be completely hidden for view `:)`

Hope this helps someone.